# Why my Mysql look never stops

Tags: mysql, select

My sql loop never ends why?
I have done a simple cursor while loop but I get an infinite loop and I cannot find the bug.
I don't have a performance issue its an infinite loop, I nave 35K records but the loops continues long after that untile I stops the execution and I cannot get how it can be, the loop should be the exact count that the cursor select retrieved

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tlaTempAmoutUSDTrades;
CREATE PROCEDURE tlaTempAmoutUSDTrades()
BEGIN
  DECLARE bDone INT;
  DECLARE pTradeGUID binary(16);    -- or approriate type
  DECLARE pTradeAmountUSD double;    -- or approriate type
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT t.guid FROM trades as t
    JOIN `orderslogadd` as `o` on`t`.`orderId` = `o`.`orderId`
    JOIN `currencypairs` as `ccp` on`o`.`ccpair` = `ccp`.`id`
    JOIN `currencies` as `ccy1` on`ccp`.`currency1` = `ccy1`.`id`
    JOIN `currencies` as `ccy2` on`ccp`.`currency2` = `ccy2`.`id`
    left  JOIN tlaAmountUSD tau on tau.guid = t.guid
    WHERE tau.amountUSD is  null ;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;

 setAmountUSD: LOOP
 FETCH curs INTO pTradeGUID;
        IF (bDone = 1) OR (pTradeGUID is null) THEN 
            LEAVE setAmountUSD;
        END IF;
        SET pTradeAmountUSD = (select  `crosUSDValV22`(`ccy1`.`id`,`ccy2`.`id`,`t`.`amount`,`t`.`amountCcy`,`t`.`dealtRate`,`t`.`guid`) as tradeAmountUSD
        FROM `trades` as t
        JOIN `orderslogadd` as `o` on`t`.`orderId` = `o`.`orderId`
        JOIN `currencypairs` as `ccp` on`o`.`ccpair` = `ccp`.`id`
        JOIN `currencies` as `ccy1` on`ccp`.`currency1` = `ccy1`.`id`
        JOIN `currencies` as `ccy2` on`ccp`.`currency2` = `ccy2`.`id`
        where t.guid=pTradeGUID);
        insert into tlaAmountUSD (guid,amountUSD) values (pTradeGUID,pTradeAmountUSD);

END LOOP setAmountUSD;
```

CLOSE curs;

END;

Comment: Is this your entire SP?? Where do you `END` your `Begin`? where are your delimiters?

Comment: [**How to debug small programs** http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). There's some *easy* steps you can take to *narrow down* what's causing the problem. I've suggested a few of those in my answer. I also provided a SQL Fiddle demonstration to show that you do not have an infinite loop in the cursor loop. [**SQL Fiddle here** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32fbb/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32fbb/1).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shown here, after the last row is fetched from `curs`, the continue handler will be called, `bDone` will be set to 1, and then the conditional test will be true, and the loop will be exited. This does not look like an infinite loop.

If this is the code that is actually executing, then it's just taking time to complete the process. (Maybe the query in the cursor definition is *really* slow, or the query in the body of the loop is really slow... a referenced table is locked, or the INSERT is blocking, etc.

For debugging this, you might consider adding a LIMIT 1 on the cursor query, to see if you can get it to complete one row, and see how long that takes.

You might try commenting out the body of the procedure that's doing the work, and just perform a fetch, to see how long that takes.

Also, run EXPLAIN on both queries (in the cursor, and in the loop), verify that appropriate indexes are being used, and that the query plan looks reasonable. Also test those queries, to verify they return the results you expect.

That will help narrow down where the problem is.

---

The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement shown is going to throw an error, unless you specify a different delimiter; otherwise, the first semicolon that's encountered is going to (prematurely) "end" the stored procedure definition

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE tlaTempAmoutUSDTrades()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE bDone INT;
                    ^
```

To get that procedure created, you need to do something like:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE PROCEDURE tlaTempAmoutUSDTrades()
 BEGIN
   DECLARE bDone INT;
   -- ...
 END $$

 DELIMITER ;
```

---

Comment: I don't have a performance issue its an infinite loop, I nave 35K records but the loops continues long after that untile I stops the execution and I cannot get how it can be, the loop should be the exact count that the cursor select retrieved

Comment: It's not an infinte loop in the code you've shown. [**SQL Fiddle demonstration here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32fbb/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32fbb/1). This replaces the query in cursor definition, changes the datatype of `pTradeGUID`, and removes the body of the loop. It runs just fine. As I recommended in my answer... there's some easy steps you can take to narrow down where the actual problem is. (Other notes, I never do a `SET v = (SELECT`, but if that was invalid syntax or threw an error, you should be seeing that. The `crosUSDValV22` function is also a suspect.

Comment: I strongly recommend you *narrow down* where the actual problem is. There's no way for us to debug this from where we're sitting... we're just guessing. We're not seeing the table definitions, whether there are triggers defined on `tlaAmountUSD`, the definition of the `crosUSDValV22` function. All we can do is recommend some *easy*  steps you can take towards debugging this issue. (And as I noted in my answer, it's not even clear that this is the code that's actually be executed... without a DELIMITER statement, the CREATE PROCEDURE statement is going to fail.